# How to highlight a user's current location in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using following code to get the location of user in phonegap (it works fine)

```
function getLocation() {
    var win = function(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        var myOptions = {
           center: myLatlng,
           zoom: 7,
           mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var  map_element = document.getElementById("displayMap");
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_element, myOptions);
    };

    var fail = function(e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    };

    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(win, fail);
}
```

This is working fine by centering the user's current location on the map. But I would like to show an indicator (a red dot) on the user's location. But I can see that google API provide only 3 options center, zoom and mapTypeId.

Are there any available options that can be used to highlight the position or is there a workaround?

**EDIT**

Was able to find that google maps API has a marker ho highlight any position. That looks helpful, but that shows a default red balloon, can that be modified by a custom image?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the newly released [GeolocationMarker](https://chadkillingsworth.github.io/geolocation-marker/) which is part of the [Google Maps API Utility Library](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries).

It will add a marker and accuracy circle at the user's current location. It also allows a developer to customize the marker using the `setMarkerOptions` method and specifying an `icon` property.

Answer (score 9):

Use icon inside marker like

```
    var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: "",
        icon: /bluedot.png
});
```

you can use this google map location indication circular blue dot icon similar to the google map

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pt-BR#MarkerOptions) to set  a custom image. Check the [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pt-BR) to more details about Google Maps.