# Current location marker in browser (blue circle)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to highlight a user's current location in google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175931/how-to-highlight-a-users-current-location-in-google-maps)

Is there any method to get blue circle marker in current location using javascript google maps api?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [GeolocationMarker library](https://chadkillingsworth.github.io/geolocation-marker/). It is part of the [Google Maps API Utility Library](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries).

Comment: FYI this isn't working for me as of July 2020

Answer (score 8):

Use the `navigator.geolocation` approach, and use a custom icon for your blue circle

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_geolocation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps User Location</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <style>
    html, body, #map_canvas{width:100%;height:100%;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="locate()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var im = 'http://www.robotwoods.com/dev/misc/bluecircle.png';
    function locate(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize,fail);
    }

    function initialize(position) {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                                      mapOptions);
        var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: im
        });
      }

     function fail(){
         alert('navigator.geolocation failed, may not be supported');
     }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you get the URL for the blue circle out of curiosity?

Comment: Can't really remember, might have just made it in Photoshop, feel free to save it from that URL, but that was pre-retina devices.