# How to highlight a user's current location in google maps? (Like the new google.com/maps PWA)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, progressive-web-apps

This library exists https://chadkillingsworth.github.io/geolocation-marker/ and it is an official contrib library listed https://googlemaps.github.io/libraries but it is not maintained by Google and I doubt it is what they are using on the new Google maps PWA http://google.com/maps which emulates the functionality of the Android app perfectly.

How is it possible to get the functionality of the blue circle which moves smoothly along the map as you drive/walk/move using the maps javascript API.

[Other related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712027/current-location-marker-in-browser-blue-circle) reference this library as the answer but it does not work nearly as well as the PWA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a moving blue marker, we have to get location info every second and update marker LatLng.
Browser geolocation API provides a watcher, which makes this task simple.

You can see a working example here.
https://jsfiddle.net/mi3afzal/3671m4nq/2/

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, {
    maximumAge: 0,
    timeout: 30000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
});
```

Comment: watchPosition is cool thanks, but the compass icon doesn't work now. I've tried a few variations.

Comment: when you have to implement watchPosition. there is no need for getMyLocation (compass) button. because of watchPosition will continually getting and updating your position.

Comment: getMyLocation could be handy when watchPosition has long intervals or stuck due to some reason.